# Bootstrap datetime picker is not working properly. I have pasted my code for the date picker here

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, datetimepicker

I was trying to include a datetimepicker inside my form. It is not working properly even though I tried many ways to fix it. I have pasted my code below.

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta name="description" content="">
    <meta name="author" content="">

    <title>Blank Page</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
            $(function() {
                $('#datetimepicker1').datetimepicker();
            });
    </script>
        <!-- Bootstrap core JS -->
        <script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
        <script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
        <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap core CSS -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap-datetimepicker.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
    <div id="wrapper">
        <!-- Sidebar -->
        <div id="page-wrapper">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="row">
                    <div class='col-sm-6'>
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <div class='input-group date' id='datetimepicker1'>
                                <input type='text' class="form-control" />
                                <span class="input-group-addon"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-calendar"></span>
                                </span>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /#page-wrapper -->
    </div><!-- /#wrapper -->


</body>
```

I was following the below link to implement the datetime picker.

http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

Answer (score 0):

This bootstrap-datetimepicker plugin requires the file `moment.js`. You can see it is included at the bottom of the page you linked to http://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/.

If you don't include it, this appears in the console:

[image: moment error in console.log]

When you add this JS file, it seems to work. See it in [a JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TLtY4/4/).

Answer (score 0):

Import your Javascript in order

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="js/moment.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap-datetimepicker.js"></script>
```